# Change Phone settings from Windows Phone 7 App

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I'm new to Windows Phone 7 App Programming, so I hope this question isn't stupid:

(How) can I get and SET the following settings from my Windows Phone 7 Silverlight App or are they protected.

- Data connection on/off
- 3G Connection on/off
- Wifi Connection on/off
- GPS Connection on/off
- Bluetooth Connection on/off

Comment: @Fasih, in my Windows Phone Settings it says "Bluetooth" without a dash, plus Google fight says "Bluetooth" is mentioned 10 times as many as "Blue-tooth": http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=bluetooth&word2=blue-tooth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user can change them from the settings menu, but you are unable to do it via the API. That capability is currently locked out.

Comment: Thanks Joe, thats a pity, I hoped to create an app to quickly activate/deactivate connections to save battery :'(

Answer (score 2):

You can get them but cannot set.

[Data connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[GPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.status.aspx)

I'm confused about Bluetooth. Maybe someone can narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

The user is in exclusive control of these settings as Joe mentions.

Bluetooth capability for now is not exposed through the 3rd party SDK.

Answer (score 1):

use the ConnectionSettingsTask Launcher to change the settings ...

You can modify Bluetooth , Wifi , Cellular , Airplane mode .

Check the following link

http://www.windowsphonerocks.com/phone/media/Developer/DeveloperArticles/tabid/64/Article/195/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-in-windows-phone-using-c.aspx